# How do I align these widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar

I am making a practice app in flutter and stuck on this:
How can i align widgets such that;
1. An icon stays at extreme left of appbar 
2. Text widget stays in middle. 
3. button stays at extreme right of appbar. 
[here is the image for what i am talking about](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVjlAXWCshw3IFeELs7eo67DQJJSfTl4/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use actions property in appbar and then as a child use a row. in that row you can use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween or MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround for arranging items.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using AppBar widget.

Note: If you want to implement drawer then use drawer property.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
        actions: [Icon(Icons.comment)],
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Accept my answer if it help you, so other community member can also get benefit.

Answer (score 0):

AppBar(title:Text("Your Text),leading:Icon(Icons.menu),actions:[Icon(Icons.favourite)])
Try this code